# Maybe use Erdős-Ko-Rado theorem can prove four sub-power set can not cover the whole power set

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

I meet the following problem,

> Given a set $S$ and $|S|=n, n\in \mathbf{N}^+$, $\mathcal{F_1},\mathcal{F_2}, \mathcal{F_3}, \mathcal{F_4}$ are four sub power sets defined on $S$, which only include sets sized $\frac{n}{2}$ and satisfy:
> $\forall i\in \{1,2,3,4\}$, $\forall A\ B\in \mathcal{F_i}, |A\cap B|\ge 2$.

> $\textbf{Prove:}$ $\mathcal{F_1}\cup \mathcal{F_2}\cup \mathcal{F_3}\cup \mathcal{F_4} \neq \mathcal{F}(S)$, where $\mathcal{F}(S)$ is the power set containing all the subsets sized $\frac{n}{2}$.

According to my intuition, it may be should use Erdős-Ko-Rado theorem. Unfortunately, I can't prove that proposition and even find a counter-example.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The power set includes single element sets. The restriction for the sub power set does not allow any single element sets in any of the four sub power sets. This implies that their union will not contain any single element sets, either.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. F1, F2, F3, F4 should only contain the sets sized n/2 and F(S) should be the power set contained all the sub sets sized n/2